# Extracting last 'Caused by' of stack trace with regex

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

Unfortunately, I'm not yet a regex expert and therefore fighting with the following problem: 
Assuming I've got a Java stack trace including multiple chained exceptions, what I want to reach is extracting the last line starting with "Caused by".

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Something bad happened
     at com.example.myproject.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:60)
.
.
Caused by: com.example.myproject.MyProjectServletException
.
.
Caused by: This is the line I want to capture
```

So far, I found `Caused by.(?!.*Caused by)` based on negative lookahead, giving me the last "Caused by" (but not the rest of the line) after I have removed all the tabs and spaces. Is there any approach giving me the result that I want? If all whitespace has to be removed, that's ok for me. Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, I think I forgot something very important. Using 'substring' would be a perfect solution in Java, but what I need is a regex which I can use for a grok pattern in Logstash.

Comment: I assume that you've been forced to parse the stacktrace and don't have access to the root `Throwable`?

Comment: What  I need to capture is the whole line starting with 'Caused by' up to the line break.

Comment: Are you able to use specific group of regex?

Comment: I don't know what Logstash and grok are exactly built upon, but I guess not.

Comment: Hmm. If it would support groups then you could simply write `[\\S\\s]*(Caused by:.*)` and use result from group 1. You could also try using `(?m)^Caused by:.*?$(?![\\s\\S]*Caused by:)`.

Comment: I don't know if regex flavor used there supports `\K` (reset of match). If it does then you could try with `[\S\s]*\KCaused by:.*`. This would discard `[\S\s]*` from matched text and wouldn't require using groups.

Comment: @Pshemo This is really nice idea! However, seems like grok does not support \K, didn't get that to work in grok debugger ...

Comment: That means java tag must be removed. And Grok regex is built on Oniguruma that does not support `\K`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a non-lookaround based solution based on *greedy quantifier*:

```
\A[\s\S]*\nCaused by:\s*(?<LastCausedBy>.*)\Z
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP8yB3/1)

The pattern matches

- `\A` - the start of a string
- `[\s\S]*` - any 0+ characters as many as possible (actually, grabbing all the text to  the end and then moving backwards - backtracking - to find the last...)
- `\nCaused by:` - newline followed with `Caused by:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `(?<LastCausedBy>.*)` - any 0+ characters other than a newline (captured into a `LastCausedBy` named group
- `\Z`  - end of string

Tested at [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/):

[image]

Comment: +1 The really smart thing about this answer is the use of `[\s\S]*\n` for this string containing newlines since the greedy operator will consume everything to the end of the string and then the engine will backtrack until it hits the first newline. This is a great way to start at the last line of a multiline string, I will remember this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use `substring` in combination with [`lastIndexOf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm) to get the last occurance of `Caused by`

Like that:

```
String lastCaused = yourStacktraceAsString.substring(yourStacktraceAsString.lastIndexOf("Caused by"));
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, that's exactly what I would need If I could do that in pure Java. However, I'm forced to use regex due to Logstash/grok.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a regular expression, but in this case, it may be simpler just to substring. Assuming your exception stacktrace is captured in a String call ex:

```
ex.substring(ex.lastIndexOf('Caused by:'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Pshemo, your ideas brought me towards the solution. After hours of trial and error, the following pattern works as expected:

```
(?m)(Caused by:)(?![\s\S.]*Caused by).*$
```

That's pretty close to your suggestions in the comments!

Comment: I have just checked and `\A[\s\S]*\nCaused by:\s*(?<LastCausedBy>.*)\Z` seems to be working well. I do not think you need any lookarounds here, they just slow the matching.

Comment: Your regex needs [124 steps](https://regex101.com/r/pS1sT4/1) to find the match and [mine needs just 65](https://regex101.com/r/lP8yB3/1).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for the advice. I will consider this in my Logstash pattern! +1

Comment: Woah that is an awesome regex online tester in @WiktorStribiżew's comment! I've never seen one that tells me the number of steps the engine uses, thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Note you can actually get once less step if you omit the `^` since the greedy operator will take everything starting from the beginning anyway.

Comment: @darkwing I'd rather keep anchors, explicit anchors help much to understand what they are supposed to match even if viewed out of the coding context. Note that the number of steps at regex101.com does not directly prove that a regex is more efficient than  another one.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are tricky, fragile, and hard to read and maintain. Negative lookahead makes that worse. Use them only when needed. I would recommend simply iterating `text.split("\n")`, looking for lines that start with `Caused by:`, and keeping the one at the end of the loop.